# Why does "pgrep -O 600" fail in an LXC? procps bug?

Tags: linux, debian, lxc, proxmox, pgrep

Debian 12.2 in an unpriviledged LXC (proxmox). It's almost 11:45 AM local time. At 5:00 AM in the morning, cron started a script:

```
USER      PID    %CPU %MEM  VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
jan       26633  0.0  0.0   8500  2056 ?       S    05:00   0:00 /usr/sbin/CRON -f
```

I'm using `pgrep -f CRON -O 600` and I expect pgrep to return PID 26633, because the process is way older than 600 seconds. But pgrep returns nothing. If I leave out the `-O`, it correctly returns the PID.

Doing the same on the host machine, i.e. outside of the LXC, it works correctly.
As pgrep uses procps, I looked there.
`ps -o etime -p $pid` in the LXC: `441077225-02:04:48`  (wrong, because since 5:00, ~6:45h passed)
`ps -o etime -p $pid` on the host: `06:43:29`           (correct)

Would that be a bug in procps or does it rather have to do with LXC?

Comment: Looks like it's caused by LXC: if I attach with privileges on a real root LXC container (`lxc-attach -e -n somecontainer`) and then use inside the container `umount /proc/uptime`, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LXC mounts a fake `/proc/uptime` to simulate the uptime of the container rather than the host's uptime, since this property is not namespaced. Here on a (root) LXC container:

```shell
# findmnt /proc/uptime
TARGET       SOURCE              FSTYPE     OPTIONS
/proc/uptime lxcfs[/proc/uptime] fuse.lxcfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other
```

But there's no such provision for each process' `stat` pseudo-file  in `/proc/PID/stat`.

So when `pgrep` compares time, it makes the difference between current `/proc/uptime` and the `starttime` field of `/proc/PID/stat` as described in [`proc(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [procps sources](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/v4.0.2/library/include/pids.h?ref_type=tags#L169):

> ```c
>     PIDS_TIME_ELAPSED,      //     real     *  derived from stat: (/proc/uptime - start_time) / hertz
> ```

Since the container's `/proc/uptime` is faked by LXC (I guess by using host's `/proc/uptime` minus LXC container's pid 1 start time), the final result gets the start time of the container *subtracted*, resulting in a negative value initially (and for some time, but still wrong anyway if/when it becomes positive later) which is unexpected, since the system uptime is supposed to be greater than the target's process start_time (possibly adjusted by a factor of `$(getconf CLK_TCK)`). *procps* tools cannot cope with this correctly.

I don't know about a workaround: if `/proc/uptime` is restored to its host value, then `pgrep -O` or `ps -o etime -p` will compute the correct value, but any tool using the system uptime will now get the host's uptime instead of the container's (faked) uptime.

Comment: Actually I guess adding pid 1's start_time to compute  PIDS_TIME_ELAPSED could fix it (even if on the host it's not 0, but usually a small value accounting for the time taken by the kernel to start init), but this wouldn't work on systems where /proc is mounted with hidepid=1 or 2.